# Is 不死身 a possible adjective to use with regard to likely immunity to the COVID-19 virus?

Tags: word-choice

Were I to think that a demographic such as young, healthy adults might have "near immunity" to COVID-19, the Japanese that comes to my mind is **不死身**.

> 若くて、健康がようさそうなので、田中さんはCOVID-19に不死身でしょうか。

general context: "Everyone says not to do Y because X might happen. But you want to express a brazen disregard for that advice. You want to express that you could care less if X happens to you and/or, you consider it impossible X could possibly happen to you (for whatever reason)."

> いや、私は不死身です。

Is that correct? What is the correct word that sounds natural in a conversation?

Comment: 不死身 means "immortal" rather than "immune"...

Comment: @naruto yes. I see the kanji for "death" in the word. So, i don't know the correct word for a brazen expression of "I am immune to that".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

不死身 is inappropriate because it means "immortal" rather than "immune". It doesn't work even as a joke because ～に不死身だ is not a thing. (If someone is "immortal only to one thing", doesn't that mean he is not immortal in the first place?)

"To be immune to ～" is ～に免疫がある (lit. "have immunity against ～"), so you can say 新型コロナウイルスに免疫がある. (Strictly speaking, COVID-19に免疫がある is incorrect because COVID-19 [is a disease name](https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/technical-guidance/naming-the-coronavirus-disease-(covid-2019)-and-the-virus-that-causes-it), not a virus name.) Alternatively you can say ～に耐性がある ("to be resistant to ～"). Whether they work as serious statements or as sarcastic remarks completely depends on the context.

Comment: Can you really not use 免疫 with diseases? Saying you are immune against a particular disease is perfectly valid English, if not the most natural.

Comment: IMO you can use it like that in everyday speech (like in English), but in technical/medical speech it’s more accurate/correct to say that you have immunity to the virus, since that is what you have antibodies for.

Comment: @Christer I found many English examples of "immune to cervical cancer" but almost no example of 頸癌への免疫/頚癌に免疫/etc, so there might be some difference in acceptance between the two languages. Either way, it's always safer to say "immune to HPV".